# Meteor getting caught in infinite loop in Tracker

Tags: meteor

This is further information from a previous submission but I thought it would be clearer if I posted this separately.

A helper is returning a collection query:

```
Template.clientGrid.helpers({
  'programs': function () {
  var fullNameP = Session.get('clientName');
  return Programs.find({FullName: fullNameP});
  }
});
```

In the template it's printing out properties from 'programs'. For example:

```
...
{{#each programs}}
  <p>{{formatCampYear CampYear}}: {{formatNotes Notes}}</p>
{{/each}}
....
```

Nothing special going on. So, if the FullName is Jane Doe, and she's got 6 documents in the programs collection, it will print the six properties in the template. But the page is getting caught in a while-loop inside [Tracker](https://gist.github.com/deanius/b75d203332e3becaf64f) (see line 449 the while-loop 'recompute all pending computations') after the properties finish printing. The CPU is tied up and prevents certain page operations. If any of you harder-core guys and gals have any clue as to what this means, perhaps I can sleuth out the problem. Here's a copy of the while loop itself (just in isolation):

```
// recompute all pending computations
  while (pendingComputations.length) {
    var comp = pendingComputations.shift();
    comp._recompute();
    if (comp._needsRecompute()) {
      pendingComputations.unshift(comp);
    }

    if (! options.finishSynchronously && ++recomputedCount > 1000) {
      finishedTry = true;
      return;
    }
  }
```

EDIT: Here's the event map that setting the session. There doesn't seem to be anything suspicious. Since I'm pre-production, I'm not doing any updates to the collection. It's pretty much just static at this point.

```
Template.clientSearchButton.events({
  'click #client-search-button': function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var clientFullName = document.getElementById('full-name').value.toUpperCase();
  Session.set('clientName', clientFullName);
  mapAddress = Demographic.find({ "FullName": clientFullName }).map(function (a) { return (a.Address + " " + a.City + " " + a.State + " " + a.Country); });
  Meteor.myFunctions.initialize();
  }
});
```

Comment: Under what conditions is clientName being set? How often is the Programs collection updated? Can you provide the code for either of those pieces?

Comment: Found the problem. It was the register.helper formatCampYear that was in charge of assisting in some formatting of the output. It was setting a session that another register helper was using as well. There was a clash of session sets.

Comment: I wondered if it was a loop related to sessions. Glad you figured it out!